# PHP move_uploaded_files and copy not working

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload

Both the functions work for file whose size is less than 10MB, but it doesn't copy when the file size is more than 10MB.

php.ini files have following:

```
post_max_size = 300M
upload_max_filesize = 300M
memory_limit = 128M
```

Destination directory has required permissions as it is working for smaller files.

Comment: Sp what does your http servers error log file say and does your `phpinfo()` function really confirm that your settings got loaded? In other words: did you really restart the http server after changing the configuration?

Comment: phpinfo() confirms the setting have been loaded. Could not find any error in the server logs.

Comment: Please make sure the script is not terminated prior to finishing normally. You can write some test output into the log file for that _after_ you tried to move the file. That will narrow down where to look for the issue. Also you want to post the relevant sections of your code in the question.

Comment: there's no php here or any code associated with uploading files.

Comment: Oh, you do not have the suhosin security extension loaded into php, do you?

Comment: I turned on the warning, it is giving  copy(): Filename cannot be empty in /var/www/html/modules/nsc/nsc.php. This is only when the file size is more than 10MB, else it is working fine.

Comment: So where in that code you supplied are you uploading files/ copying files?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your php file

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

These setting will override whatever php.ini has.

I suspect you might be looking at the wrong php.ini